# Simple array sort/check + Divide and conquer version

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was wondering if anyone can tell me the error with my code. I'm trying to make an algorithm that searches through elements in an array, and returns 'true' if the element is 'less than i' and 'greater than u'. I can't quite understand why this doesn't seem to work. It sometimes returns true but appears to ignore the first element of the array, others not so much.

Additionally to this, I want to experiment with a 'divide and conquer' version of this, now I understand some of the theory behind this. The use of a 'pivot' point and dividing the array into two smaller problems but have no idea how to implement it, if anyone can elaborate on either of these issues I'd be most grateful. thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool ArrayCheck(int length) {
    int A[] = { 5, 10, 20, 25, 50 };
    int i = 40;  //less Than
    int u = 15;  //Greater Than

    for (int Count = 0; Count < length; Count++) { //Counter
        if (A[Count] <= i && A[Count] >= u) { //Checker
            return true;
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << ArrayCheck(5);
}
```

Comment: Well, break; should be removed because it's unreachable...

Comment: Sorry i left that in, It was originally not there, just an experiment to try and solve my problem, thanks for the reply

Comment: your method will return false at the first iteration of the loop because `A[0] = 5` and `5 < u`

Comment: Did you mean all array elements should fall between limits i and u ?

Comment: OUTPUT: TRUE if A contains an element which is both greater than l and less than u, FALSE otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the else supposed to be there? It seems like the `else { return false }` line should just be removed and you could add `return false` after the entire loop...

Should be something like:

```
for(...)
{
    if(condition)
    {
         return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see your reply about showing you the updated code, the change I made was exactly the same as your example, still seems to be messing me around with results

Comment: @user1289022 the first element of your array will cause the code to return true.

Comment: @user1289022 have you changed the first element?

Comment: Okay everything I thought was the problem appears not to be, again I'm all out of ideas

Comment: Problem solved, my own stupidity reading my results caused a problem. thank you for your time sir. Any chance you would know how to adjust this to use the 'divide and conquer' method?

Comment: Do you mean breaking the list into parts? Have you covered recursion yet? It would be kind of like this if you use recursion: 
check(arr, size) { if size == 1 return condition; else check(arr, size / 2) && check (arr + size / 2, size / 2); }

Comment: i have done a few things with recursion, thanks for your help buddy its been very useful. I'll do my best to figure out the rest of the code from your example. thanks again